# Different behavior of `vim -R` and `view`

Tags: vim

Manual page on vim (`$ man vim`) states:

```
  view      Start in read-only mode.  You will be protected from writing the files.  Can also be done with the "-R" argument.
```

But, they have major differences.

When starting vim as `vim -R` the syntax coloring works.
But when started as `view` syntax coloring doesn't work.

`view` doesn't support vertical splitting, I tried `Ctrl+w v`, `:vs` and `-O` command line option.

Does `view` have a separate config? Or maybe it is completely separate from vim itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, on that server (not administered by me) `view` is a symlink to `/bin/vi`, while `vi` is aliased to `/usr/bin/vim` system-wide.

Both binaries, `vi` and `vim`, use the name they were launched with ([`argv[0]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argv)) to determine the behavior – whether or not to be in readonly mode. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20355/23667 for details.

To fix my issue, I just added `alias view='vim -R'` to my personal `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: On my box, `vi`, `vim` and `view` all end up in `/usr/bin/vim.basic`. and coloring is OK.

Comment: Are you on Arch Linux? Arch has separate vi and Vim packages, and view is from vi. Try rview if you have vim.

Comment: It's a server I use over ssh with Scientific Linux on it.